# There was a error named Undefined Index on Select Option CI3

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, view, codeigniter-3

I just had an error in the form of undefined index in the select option so the table that was written couldn't appear. I've made sure there are no typos at all in writing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0rzR.png)

My Databases :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a91o.png)

My View Codes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrHOR.png)

Can someone explain how it could be error?

I've tried replacing nama_lab with another variable but the result is still the same.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) **as you were asked to do when registering**
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)